# Inherit class and modify columns in Openerp

Tags: inheritance, odoo

I'm working on a module in Openerp, and I'd like to inherit a class from another module, but I don't need every single column that's in the other class.

This is my class:

```
class BookingManagement(orm.Model):
    _name = 'booking.management'

    _inherit = 'res.partner.address.contact'

    _description = 'Booking management'

    _columns = {
        'guests': fields.integer('Number of guests', required=True),
        'check_in': fields.date('From', required=True),
        'check_out': fields.date('To', required=True),
        'special_requests': fields.text('Special requests')
    }
```

And this is *res.partner.address.contact*

```
class res_partner_address_contact(orm.Model):
    _name = "res.partner.address.contact"

    _description = "Address Contact"

    def [...]

    def [...]

    _columns = {
        'complete_name': fields.function(_name_get_full, string='Name', size=64, type="char", store=False, select=True),
        'name': fields.char('Name', size=64, ),
        'last_name': fields.char('Last Name', size=64, required=True),
        'first_name': fields.char('First Name', size=64),
        'mobile': fields.char('Mobile', size=64),
        'fisso': fields.char('Phone', size=64),
        'title': fields.many2one('res.partner.title', 'Title', domain=[('domain', '=', 'contact')]),
        'website': fields.char('Website', size=120),
        'address_id': fields.many2one('res.partner.address', 'Address'),
        'partner_id': fields.related(
            'address_id', 'partner_id', type='many2one', relation='res.partner', string='Main Employer'),
        'lang_id': fields.many2one('res.lang', 'Language'),
        'country_id': fields.many2one('res.country', 'Nationality'),
        'birthdate': fields.char('Birthdate', size=64),
        'active': fields.boolean('Active', help="If the active field is set to False,\
                 it will allow you to hide the partner contact without removing it."),
        'email': fields.char('E-Mail', size=240),
        'comment': fields.text('Notes', translate=True),
        'photo': fields.binary('Photo'),
        'function': fields.char("Function", size=64),
        'function_id': fields.many2one('res.contact.function', 'Function'),
    }

    def [...]
```

Let's say that the only columns I need are '**last_name**', '**first_name**', '**email**' and '**mobile**'.
How do I do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Odoo there are two kinds of inheritance you can use.
The first one is obtained by setting (as you did)

```
_name = 'booking.management'

_inherit = 'res.partner.address.contact'
```

the result are two table, the original one (res_partner_address_contact) which is unchanged, and yours (booking_management) which contains the four field you declared plus the ID of the first table (you need to declare this field as well)

The second one is obtained by declaring

```
_name = 'res.partner.address.contact'

_inherit = 'res.partner.address.contact'
```

the result is the table res_partner_address_contact with the extra fields you declared.

Said that, you just can't obtain a table with only the four field you need. It's an all or nothing situation.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to inherit `'res.partner.address.contact'` and just use `last_name', 'first_name', 'email' and 'mobile'` inherit like you did and add them in the xml view, because as you wrote you specify that `'res.partner.address.contact'`  should be used in your model.

If you want a `contact` informations  use `One2many` to link many contacts or `Many2one` to link one contact.